# kafka streams processor API functions not getting called

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am newbie in kafka. Written my first code for kafka streams with processor API, but somehow control is not reaching either of the init(), process() or punctuate() function.Fact of the matter is, control not entering the EnrollmentStreamProcessor.java while it should at " `.addProcessor("PROCESS1", () -> new EnrollmentStreamProcessor(), "SOURCE");` " 
of topology building - isn't that so?

Here is the summary of what I have written:

### Producer.java

```
{
public static void main(){
...

topology.addSource("SOURCE", topicName)

    .addProcessor("PROCESS1", () -> new EnrollmentStreamProcessor(), "SOURCE");
    //.addStateStore(pdStore, "PROCESS1")
    //.addSink("SINK1", "sink-topic1", "PROCESS2");

    KafkaStreams streaming = new KafkaStreams(topology, streamingConfig);
    streaming.start();  

...

producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("patient-data-demo", 
pd.toString(), pIdent.toString()));
...
}

}
```

### EnrollmentStreamProcessor.java

```
{
...

init(...){
...
}

process(...){
...
}
punctuate(...){
...
}
```

Producer is running fine without error but EnrollmentStreamProcessor is not getting called.what am I missing?

in other words, when exactly init() method gets called by stream thread? Any stream thread life-cycle control flow for Low level processor API will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you pre-created the topic "SOURCE" prior to running your application?

Comment: Is `topicName == "patient-data-demo"` ? Can you verify that the data is written into the topic?